# MassTranist ESB support for other technology

Tags: masstransit

Please let us know whether MassTransit ESB supports any/all of the following technologies?

- BPEL
- jBPM
- JSR -223 (Scripting)
- OGNL Filters

As far as I analyzed there does not seem to any support.Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know what any of those are, I'm going to say no.

MassTransit is a .NET based ESB, not Java based. Google searching these technologies it appears they are all Java based. It wouldn't make sense for them to be supported directly within MassTransit. MassTransit is more just about sending and receiving data, Pub/Sub, and related activities.

There is a library being worked on for .NET/Java working together via MassTransit, [CrossTown](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit-CrossTown). But that doesn't include support for these technologies.

Comment: I dont disagree with you in that MT is a .NET ESB, however it would make total sense to be able to communicate between services in different languages when considering distributed systems. SOA allows for the use of different languages, because everything is self contained. If the service calls were just http requests from one service to another, rather than a pub/sub relation, then it would work fine, and you would not be limited to hiring talent strictly based on syntax preference or language snobs. I have been playing with MT's port for Java "CrossTown", the idea is pretty interesting.